# Does 'async with' Close An aiohttp.ClientSession() Object Gracefully Upon Timeout even without calling asyncio.sleep(0)?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiohttp, python-3.10

I am aware that using 'async with' as a context manager will allow us to call aiohttp.ClientSession() object's .close() method automatically.

```
#1:
async def get_url(**kwargs):   
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:  
        async with session.get(**kwargs) as response:  
            return await response.json()
```

However, what I'm concerned about is this part in the documentation where [we are advised to call asyncio.sleep(0) just before invoking the aiohttp.ClientSession() object's .close() method. See 'Graceful Shutdown'.](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_advanced.html#client-session)

My solution was to write my function this way:

```
#2:
async def get_url(**kwargs):                       
    session=aiohttp.ClientSession()    
    try:
        response=await session.get(**kwargs)       
        await asyncio.sleep(0)                     #Sleep, then close session first
        await session.close()                      #You will see errors if this is commented out.
        return await response.json()
    except:
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
        await session.close()
```

However, I can't help but wonder why so many people call aiohttp.ClientSession() like in #1 if we were supposed to await asyncio.sleep(0) before running awaiting the .close() method to be run. As far as I understand, `async with` only calls an object's close method without adding an asyncio.sleep(0) statement just before that.

Comment: Looking at the documentation, the sleep is not called before the `session.close` but before `loop.close` - and only in specific situations (if you get warning messages)

Comment: Hi, @AndrejKesely, I'm trying to handle timeout errors, which is why I want to make sure that asyncio.sleep(0) is called. But can I not call it immediately after the timeout error takes place and just before session.close()?

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround in the comments on the original GitHub issue for this
https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/1925#issuecomment-708690799

It has a more graceful solution than the 0 sleep

Comment: Hi, Jim, thanks for the suggestion! I tried adding breakpoints to the code in client_proto.py as they suggested in that github post, and the issue seemed to be fixed there, but close() and __del__ in asyncio's selector_events.py were never called, not even when I added in their suggested fix (which froze the program in its tracks).

Comment: Also, the ClientSession object is not closed by the 'await with' method (at least it seemed that way when I tried printing out its status after encapsulating 'await session.get' in another try-except block.

Is it still good enough if I just call session.close() in my loop as above?

Comment: Also, oddly enough, session.close() does not even call close() and del in asyncio's selector_events.py